# Salt command archive.cmd_unzip fails with template type jinja

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am looking at options to unzip a zip file, while parsing it for some variables (templated using jinja) using saltstack.
Although the salt module `archive.cmd_unzip` unzips the file, it simply fails to work with jinja. I tried the command:

```
archive.cmd_unzip template=jinja mytest.zip '/unzipped/'
```

It simply fails with an error:

```
Passed invalid arguments: expected str, bytearray, or unicode.

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/cmdmod.py", line 153, in _render
    fp_.write(salt.utils.stringutils.to_str(contents))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/stringutils.py", line 118, in to_str
    raise TypeError('expected str, bytearray, or unicode')
TypeError: expected str, bytearray, or unicode
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Salt does not support Python 2 any more. You probably need to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved by using the code i have given below:

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('sampleDir.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
    zipObj.extractall()
```

this code will create or extract the file in the same directory if you want to extract in a different directory then you must.
import

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('sampleDir.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
    zipObj.extractall('temp')
```

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with Salt or jinja templating

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
salt '*' archive.unzip template=jinja /tmp/zipfile.zip /tmp/{{grains.id}}/ excludes=file_1,file_2
```

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2019.2/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.archive.html#salt.modules.archive.unzip

Comment: This did not help. the template jinja is for the options provided in the cmd line itself. It is not parsing the files.

Comment: @SilentCoder yes, that's what the `template` option does. If you want to do something with the unzipped files, then you need a second step.